# Android Studio: Build Error When Running Main Method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Issue I am facing:

1. Created new Java Class called "Hello"
2. Attempted to run main method:

public class Hello {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

3: Error I received:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Initialization script 'C:\Users\User25\AppData\Local\Temp\Hellos_main__.gradle' line: 21
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not create task ':app:Hellos.main()'.
> SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

---

Things I tried: Ran the "Hello" class with coverage and works just fine. However, I have no idea why I can't simply run the code. I have probably spent a good 2 to 3 hours searching online on how to resolve this issue but couldn't find a solution. Someone had the same problem on the Android Studios forum but nobody got back with a solution. Would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

[Link to exercise I am trying to follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOWwO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `main()` method in Android. the main entry point is an Activity as specified in AndroidManifest.xml (usually called `MainActivity`).

Answer (score 0):

For running your Java code follows the following steps:

1. Go to File > New > New Module and select Java Library
2. Create a Java Library and add your code inside it
3. Run the code by clicking the green arrow as follows:
   [image]

You can find more information in this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUFPgKsYWvA&ab_channel=ForTheGreaterGood)